# Kivy demo pictures - I am trying to modify the Class Rule <Picture> and clear the canvas.after

Tags: python, kivy

I modified the Pictures demo example from Kivy. I changed the canvas.before to canvas.after in the .kv file to hide my pictures with the white cover. I added a button in the .py file to clear the canvas.after on_press to remove the white cover and show my pictures. The problem is I can only access the root Class in the .kv file which is FloatLayout:. I need to access the class rule : in order to able to clear the canvas.after using the canvas.after.class() function.

Here is the .py file:

```
    #!/usr/bin/kivy
'''
Pictures demo
=============

This is a basic picture viewer, using the scatter widget.
'''

import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from glob import glob
from random import randint
from os.path import join, dirname
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
# FIXME this shouldn't be necessary
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Picture(Scatter):
    '''Picture is the class that will show the image with a white border and a
    shadow. They are nothing here because almost everything is inside the
    picture.kv. Check the rule named <Picture> inside the file, and you'll see
    how the Picture() is really constructed and used.

    The source property will be the filename to show.
    '''

    source = StringProperty(None)


class PicturesApp(App):

    def build(self):

        # the root is created in pictures.kv
        root = self.root

        btn1 = Button(text='Show Pictures', size=(100, 50), size_hint=(None, None), pos=(600, 50))
        btn1.bind(on_press=root.canvas.after.clear())
        root.add_widget(btn1)

        # get any files into images directory
        curdir = dirname(__file__)
        for filename in glob(join(curdir, 'images', '*')):
            try:
                # load the image
                picture = Picture(source=filename, rotation=randint(-30, 30))
                # add to the main field
                root.add_widget(picture)

            except Exception as e:
                Logger.exception('Pictures: Unable to load <%s>' % filename)

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PicturesApp().run()
```

Here is the .kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import kivy kivy
#:import win kivy.core.window

FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            source: 'data/images/background.jpg'
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        size_hint: 1, None
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        height: 44
        Image:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 24, 24
            source: 'data/logo/kivy-icon-24.png'
        Label:
            height: 24
            text_size: self.width, None
            color: (1, 1, 1, .8)
            text: 'Kivy %s - Pictures' % kivy.__version__



<Picture>:
    # each time a picture is created, the image can delay the loading
    # as soon as the image is loaded, ensure that the center is changed
    # to the center of the screen.
    on_size: self.center = win.Window.center
    size: image.size
    size_hint: None, None

    Image:
        id: image
        source: root.source

        # create initial image to be 400 pixels width
        size: 80, 80 / self.image_ratio

        # add shadow background
        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            BorderImage:
                source: 'shadow32.png'
                border: (36,36,36,36)
                size:(self.width+72, self.height+72)
                pos: (-36,-36)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending where you want to clear the canvas: in build() method, you can do

```
picture.ids.image.canvas.clear()
#or
picture.ids['image'].canvas.clear()
```

If within the Picture class:

```
self.ids.image.canvas.clear()
```

Alternatively, you can change it without clearing, here's how:

```
class Picture(Scatter):
    visible = BooleanProperty(True)
```

In .kv:

```
<Picture>:
...
     Image:
      ...
        canvas.after:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,1,1 if root.visible else 0)
...
```

Or something like that.